# Odoo 10: Getting a view like invoice _line_ids from Invoice module

Tags: python, xml, module, customization, odoo

I am extending the Employees module to list all the devices which an employee got from the company. Below is my models.py :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import models, fields, api

class device_types(models.Model):
    _name = "device.types"
    name = fields.Char()

class device_names(models.Model):
    _name = "device.names"
    name = fields.Char()
    #devices_names = fields.Many2one('hr.employee')


class devices(models.Model):
    _name = "devices"

    #devices_types = fields.Many2one('device.types')
    devices_id = fields.Many2one('hr.employee')
    devices_types = fields.Char()
    devices_names = fields.Char()



    #employee_id = fields.Many2one('hr.employee')


class employee_devices(models.Model):
     _inherit = 'hr.employee'
     #devices_lines_ids = fields.One2many('devices','devices_id',string='Device Lines',readonly=True, states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]}, copy=True)
     devices_lines_ids = fields.One2many('devices','devices_id',string='Device Lines')
     #devices_names = fields.Many2one('devices')
     #devices_types = fields.Many2one('devices')
     devices_types = fields.One2many('devices','devices_types')
     devices_names = fields.One2many('devices.names')
```

and my view.xml :

```
<odoo>
  <data>
    <!-- explicit list view definition -->

    <record id="invoice_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="model">hr.employee</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_form" />
    <field name="priority" eval="1"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml"> 
        <xpath expr="//notebook//page[@name='hr_settings']" position="after">
         <page name="Devices" string="Devices" groups="hr.group_hr_user">
                                <group>
                                    <group string="Devices" name="devices_group">
                                        <field name="devices_lines_ids" nolabel="1" widget="one2many_list" mode="tree" >
                                         <tree string="Devices" editable="bottom">
                                           <field name="devices_types" />
                                              <field name="devices_names"/> 
                                         </tree> 
                                        </field>
                                    </group>
                                </group>
        </page>
       </xpath>
    </field>
</record>


  </data>
</odoo>
```

and i am able to achieve this :
[image]

But I want to have a drop down menu in Devices Types and Devices names columns with the ability to Create new types and names. I have tried different combinations as you can see in the comments of models.py. How can I get that drop down menus in my view???

In short, I want this type of view where i can edit each column inside the tree view and some columns have drop down menu:[image]

Answer (score 1):

Fixed. my updated modules.py :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import models, fields, api

class device_types(models.Model):
    _name = "device.types"
    name = fields.Char()

class device_names(models.Model):
    _name = "device.names"
    name = fields.Char()


class devices(models.Model):
    _name = "devices"
    employee_name = fields.Many2one('hr.employee')
    devices_names = fields.Many2one('device.names')
    devices_types = fields.Many2one('device.types')



class employee_devices(models.Model):
     _inherit = 'hr.employee'
     devices_lines_ids = fields.One2many('devices','employee_name',string='Device Lines',states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]}, copy=True)
```

and my views.xml:

```
    <odoo>
    <data>
    <!-- explicit list view definition -->

    <record id="invoice_form" model="ir.ui.view">
      <field name="model">hr.employee</field>
      <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_form" />
      <field name="priority" eval="1"/>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//notebook//page[@name='hr_settings']" position="after">
          <page name="Devices" string="Devices" groups="hr.group_hr_user">
            <group>
                <field name="devices_lines_ids" nolabel="1" widget="one2many_list" mode="tree">
                  <tree string="Devices" editable="bottom">
                    <field name="devices_types" />
                    <field name="devices_names"/>
                  </tree>
                </field>
            </group>
          </page>
        </xpath>
      </field>
    </record>
  </data>
</odoo>
```

Comment: Yep you just have to create (many2one) relations to `device.names` and `device.types`.